# Using two packages with tons of commands having same names

Tags: errors, packages

I write a review paper in which various coathors are willing to insert equations from their prior works. Their latex manuscripts seem to use incompatible packages. In particular, the `qcircuit` package and the `quantikz` library of `tikz` have tons of commands with identical names. I am wondering if there exists some elegant solution, such as loading a package locally, or anything like that.

Comment: You may just load the pdfs of your TikZ created with standalone, so you only worry with half the commands.

Comment: Looks like `quantikz` is an upgrade. From the manual - "IX. CONVERTING FROM QCIRCUIT I’ve updated all of my existing teaching materials from QCircuit to Quantikz with very little trouble. There are a few standard replacements: ..." etc

Comment: Theoretically one could add prefixes to all the macros for both packages using `\let\MYname=\name`, then swap them back again as needed.